# How to load parent-child-parent associations in Rails 4?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

this is my first question on StackOverflow :)

I'm building a Rails 4 app, having trouble to figure out a good way to load records from mutilple data models. I could hard code SQL statements like an inner join, but wondering if there's any better way. Searched in existing questions on SO, but didn't find a match.

Here are my models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
end
```

**Question:** given a person Id, how should I load its associated addresses with the city information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Address.includes(:persons,:cities).where(person_id: person.id)
```

this is one of many ways.

Comment: Thanks Babar. What if I only want to select a subset of the columns? I tried with the following code, but always returned nil. 
    `class Address < ActiveRecord::Base`  
      `belongs_to :person`  
      `belongs_to :city`  
      `belongs_to :city_select_columns, -> { select("column_name"), :class_name => "City"`  
    `end`  
    
Then query with:  
    `Address.includes(:person,:city_select_columns).where(person_id: person.id)`

Comment: again joins would be better but since we are already using includes? then here it goes:<br>
Address.includes(:persons,:cities).select(cities.column1,cities.column2, persons.column1, persons.column2.....).where(person_id: person.id)